# Toggling branch tree view in GitKraken

Tags: gitkraken

Can't believe I can not figure this one out - I have two installations of gitkraken on two different machines, but the main workflow window looks different between them. One installation shows up a simplified structure of commits for all the branches:

[image: simple view]

while another renders a tree view of the workflow:

[image: desired view]

I prefer the latter over the former, but I can't figure out **how to switch between the two?**

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Increase the commit graph section width by dragging the small colored lines just left of the commit message.

Comment: That should really be highlighted on first install as I missed it completely and had to come hunting for this

Comment: Exactly the same happens to me, there is nothing to hint that you can drag that part of the graph and the documentation shows directly the graph instead of the simplified version

Answer (score 20):

It's too easy just drag the commit graph to change the view, look below image

[image]

Source: https://blog.axosoft.com/gitkraken-tips-2/